# Different of Thread start()

Tags: java, multithreading

In researching previous project coding:

I found out that using Thread with 2 different way

First is

```
TimerThread tt=new TimerThread();
tt.start();
```

Second is

```
TimerThread tt=new TimerThread();
new Thread(tt).start();
```

is there any different between these 2 code when run?

Comment: What language is this? I assume Java but it would be helpful to tag it as such

Comment: I usually find ```Runnable``` and ```ScheduledExecutorService``` to be better choices than ```TimerTask``` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

Geoffrey,

Yes. Kinda. The first option created a new TimerThread object and assigned it to the tt handle. It then accessed the start() method from that handle.

The second option created a new TimerThread object and assigned it to the tt handle. Then in the second line, created another new Thread object and assigned it to the tt handle, and then accessed the start() method through that "new" Thread object, thus orphaning the object created in the first line.

The only real difference is that option two does some unnecessary work in it's first line. I'm not 100% on this explanation, so I welcome anyone with a deeper understanding.

-Fletch

Answer (score 0):

The first option was used when TimerThread was extended from Thread, and the second option was used when the TimerThread is an interface implemented from Runnable.

Hope it helps.